# How to read image using oDatamodel V2 in sapui5?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am stuck trying to read an image from the gateway.

If I run this uri directly in the SAP gateway it runs OK and the image data is read: /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSA_USERS_SRV/UserPhotoSet('someone@gmail.com')/$value"

Now I want to read this image in my sapui5 application using the code below, but I just get the error "EventProvider sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel - No data was retrieved by service:"

What am I missing here?

```
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    oModel.read("/UserPhotoSet('someone@gmail.com')/$value", {
        success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            alert("Success read userphotto");
            img.setSrc(oData);
        },
    });
```

Comment: does the uri /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSA_USERS_SRV/UserPhotoSet('someone@gmail.com')/$value work in the browser ?

Comment: Hi! Yes it works nice in the browser!

Comment: What the response data you are getting on success of this service.

Comment: The response is this string: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERA...."

Explanation for this data:
This data is coming from a SAP table. I just get the image from the camera and concatenate the "data:image/jpeg;base64" string before setSrc of an image element. Then I save the result of getSrc from this same element using oDataModel.Create

Answer (score 1):

Don't use oModel.read(...)! In your case all you need to do is

```
img.setSrc("/path/to/my/service/UserPhotoSet('someone@gmail.com')/$value");
```

The property src of the image is a string - [it's a URI](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Image.html#getSrc)!

> Relative or absolute path to URL where the image file is stored. The
>   path will be adapted to the density aware format according to the
>   density of the device following the convention that

Of course, you have to replace "/path/to/my/service/" with the real path...

Comment: Hello Nabi! Thanks for the answer! I did what you recomended but the image does not load.
this is what I put in the src of the image in my XML fragment:

`<Image id="imgPreviewForm" class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" width="300px" height="150px" visible="true" src="/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSA_USERS_SRV/UserPhotoSet('someone@gmail.com')/$value"></Image>`

In the network the response only says "This request has no response data available" and I see no error there :/

Comment: Typically, with $value you would return the real image file content instead of a base64 string. After you added some additional hints I can I can see your service returns a the file as a base64 string, correct? And this is because the file is stored this way in the DB. I'm not sure if the Image control can handle Data URIs correctly. Anyway, what you could do is decoding the base64 string on the backend before sending it to the frontend. Doing this everytime is not what I would prefer...

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing all the details of yor service, but maybe 
the running examples on https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/08/displaying-images-in-sapui5-received-from-the-northwind-odata-service/ help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found out the issue is the way I was saving the photo from the camera is wrong, but I dont know why. I followed the steps of this blog [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/24/uploading-files-to-sap-gw-downloading-files-from-sap-gw-new-techniques/)
But i still dont know the correct way to call the post method 'your_service/UserSet(‘usermail’)/Photo' from my sapui5 application. I abandon this way and now I am send the data from the image src directly to an string, and I am doing the conversion to binary in the backend. Now the read /$value is working

Answer (score 1):

**In XML :**

```
<Image id="imgPreviewForm" 
       class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" 
       width="300px" height="150px" visible="true" src="">
</Image>
```

In Javascript Controller:

```
    var img=this.getView().byId("imgPreviewForm");
    img.setSrc("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEST_PDF_SRV/FileSet
                ('Test.jpg')/$value");
```

Comment: it,s working fine, but my aspect send single request  get more images that will be store on model. that model set to view. how can i do that way?